# java CSV file to array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I am novice to java however, I cannot seem to figure this one out.  I have a CSV file in the following format:

```
String1,String2
String1,String2
String1,String2
String1,String2
```

Each line are pairs.  The 2nd line is a new record, same with the 3rd.  In the real word the CSV file will change in size, sometimes it will be 3 records, or 4, or even 10.

My issues is how do I read the values into an array and dynamically adjust the size?  I would imagine, first we would have to parse though the csv file, get the number of records/elements, then create the array based on that size, then go though the CSV again and store it in the array.

I'm just not sure how to accomplish this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: Please don't point me to articles.  I have already tried that one, and the problem with that article is that it just keeps overwriting the values in the array, so after the parese my array size is only 2.

Comment: opencsv library.  Also, just use a `List` instead of a fixed-size array so it can grow on demand.  Convert to an array later if you really must.

Comment: `String.split(",")` will split a line into an array. Collect each line in a `List<String[]>`.

Comment: or use an arraylist instead of an array.

Comment: @Tichodroma only in naive code - it'll break if you have an embedded comma in a string.

Comment: @Alnitak Sure, but as far as we can tell, there is no `,` in a cell.

Comment: Sorry I am not following how to do this.

Comment: So I do the string split in my while loop.  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { String.split(",")}?

Comment: Look at my post this is exactly what you need look at the correct answer.

Comment: Just replace "yourfile" with the complete path to your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ArrayList instead of Array. An ArrayList is a dynamic array. ex.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("yourfile"));
ArrayList<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] record = new String[2];
while(scan.hasNext())
{
    record = scan.nextLine().split(",");
    records.add(record);
}
//now records has your records.
//here is a way to loop through the records (process)
    for(String[] temp : records)
    {
        for(String temp1 : temp)
        {
            System.out.print(temp1 + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Just replace "yourfile" with the absolute path to your file.

You could do something like this.

More traditional for loop for processing the data if you don't like the first example:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < records.get(i).length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(records.get(i)[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Both for loops are doing the same thing though.

Comment: So the arraylist appears to work.  Now how do i get the data out of the arraylist.  Do i just treat it like a 2d array?

Comment: I added code for processing the data look at the second for loop it loops through the arraylist returning the String array (row) then the inner loop loops through the array (columns).  Right now i just printed them to the console but you can do whatever you want inside the loops.  Also please mark as correct if this helped you.

Comment: Thanks this helped alot.  Having an example and explanation helped. At least you didn't point me to an article.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply read the CSV into a 2-dimensional array just in 2 lines with the open source library [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial).

Refer to the following code as an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    /**
     * ---------------------------------------
     * Read CSV rows into 2-dimensional array
     * ---------------------------------------
     */

    // 1st, creates a CSV parser with the configs
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(new CsvParserSettings());

    // 2nd, parses all rows from the CSV file into a 2-dimensional array
    List<String[]> resolvedData = parser.parseAll(new FileReader("/examples/example.csv"));

    // 3rd, process the 2-dimensional array with business logic
    // ......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- Use the Java Collections rather than arrays, specifically a `List` or `Set`, to auto-expand as you add items.
- Define a class to hold your data read from CSV, instantiating an object for each row read.
- Use the *Apache Commons CSV* library to help with the chore of reading/writing CSV files.

## Class to hold data

Define a class to hold the data of each row being read from your CSV. Let's use `Person` class with a given name and surname, to be more concrete than the example in your Question.

In Java 16 and later, more briefly define the class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
record Person ( String givenName , String surname ) {}
```

In older Java, define a conventional class.

```
package work.basil.example;

public class Person {
    public String givenName, surname;

    public Person ( String givenName , String surname ) {
        this.givenName = givenName;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return "Person{ " +
                "givenName='" + givenName + '\'' +
                " | surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                " }";
    }
}
```

## Collections, not arrays

Using the [Java Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) is generally better than using mere arrays. The collections are more flexible and more powerful. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Here we will use the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) interface to collect each `Person` object instantiated from data read in from the CSV file. We use the concrete [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) implementation of `List` which uses arrays in the background. The important part here, related to your Question, is that you can add objects to a `List` **without worrying about resizing**. The `List` implementation is responsible for any needed resizing.

If you happen to know the approximate size of your list to be populated, you can supply an optional initial capacity as a hint when creating the `List`.

## Apache Commons CSV

The *Apache Commons CSV* library does a nice job of reading and writing several variants of CSV and Tab-delimited formats.

## Example app

Here is an example app, in a single `PersoIo.java` file. The `Io` is short for input-output.

Example data.

```csv
GivenName,Surname
Alice,Albert
Bob,Babin
Charlie,Comtois
Darlene,Deschamps
```

Source code.

```
package work.basil.example;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class PersonIo {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        PersonIo app = new PersonIo();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        Path path = Paths.get( "/Users/basilbourque/people.csv" );
        List < Person > people = this.read( path );
        System.out.println( "People: \n" + people );
    }

    private List < Person > read ( final Path path ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( path );
        if ( Files.notExists( path ) ) {
            System.out.println( "ERROR - no file found for path: " + path + ". Message # de1f0be7-901f-4b57-85ae-3eecac66c8f6." );
        }

        List < Person > people = List.of(); // Default to empty list.
        try {
            // Hold data read from file.
            int initialCapacity = ( int ) Files.lines( path ).count();
            people = new ArrayList <>( initialCapacity );

            // Read CSV file.
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader( path );
            Iterable < CSVRecord > records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse( reader );
            for ( CSVRecord record : records ) {
                // GivenName,Surname
                // Alice,Albert
                // Bob,Babin
                // Charlie,Comtois
                // Darlene,Deschamps
                String givenName = record.get( "GivenName" );
                String surname = record.get( "Surname" );

                // Use read data to instantiate.
                Person p = new Person( givenName , surname );

                // Collect
                people.add( p ); // For real work, you would define a class to hold these values.
            }

        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return people;
    }


}
```

When run.

> People:
>
> [Person{ givenName='Alice' | surname='Albert' }, Person{ givenName='Bob' | surname='Babin' }, Person{ givenName='Charlie' | surname='Comtois' }, Person{ givenName='Darlene' | surname='Deschamps' }]